# find the first occurence in an int array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function `int* findPair(int* data, int numEls, int first, int second)`to search in an int array data for an element equal to first followed immediately by an element second. If this situation occurs, the function returns a pointer to the element first. If the situation occurs more than once in the array, the pointer should be to the first occurrence. 
My code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* findPair(int* data, int numEls, int first, int second)
{
    int i = 0;
    int *n = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < numEls; i++) {
        if(data[i] == first && data[i + 1] == second) {
            n = &data[i];
        }

    }
    return n;

}
int main()
{
    int data[] = {1, 10, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2};
    int* p = findPair(data, 7, 1, 2);
    if (p != NULL) {
        printf("Found at position %zd\n", p - data);
    }
    else {
        puts("Not found");
    }
}
```

When I entered two `1,2`for testing and it pointed to the second occurence( position 5 instead of position 3).Any hint where I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop in the `findPair` function doesn't stop at the first occurrence of a pair. Instead it keeps going, searching for more pairs, and whenever it encounters a pair, it overwrites `n`. Therefore `n` will always point to the last occurrence (well, to the first element of the last occurrence).

You need to stop the `for` loop as soon as you find the first occurrence.

Use a `break` statement to exit prematurely from a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < numEls; i++) {
    if(data[i] == first && data[i + 1] == second) {
        n = &data[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

When the first pair is found, `n` will be set to point to the first element of a pair, and the loop will exit immediately, jumping to the `return` statement of your function.

Comment: Instead of `break;`, you could use `return &data[i];`, couldn't you?

Comment: Surely, though I thought it would be useful to introduce `break` to OP, since he seemingly didn't know about its existence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your loop always finds the rightmost pair in the array. See, if you find a match, your loop still goes on and n is later reassigned to point to other element.

Besides, if you add one more element to the array:

```
int data[] = {1, 10, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1};
int* p = findPair(data, 8, 1, 2);
```

the behaviour will become undefined (you program will probably segfault.)

So either pass array's length minus one to function, or, better, terminate the loop properly:

```
for (i = 0; i < numEls - 1; i++) {
    if(data[i] == first && data[i + 1] == second) {
        n = &data[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

As an additional small  optimization, you can avoid extra comparisons in some cases:

```
if(first != second) {
    for (i = 0; i < numEls - 1; ++i) {
        if(data[i + 1] == second) {
            if(data[i] == first) {
                n = &data[i];
                break;
            }
            else ++i;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

for (i = 0; i < numEls - 1; ++i) {
    if(data[i + 1] == first) {
        if(data[i] == first) {
            n = &data[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    else ++i;
}
return n;
```

Comment: OK: cleanup time.  This comment will be removed shortly.  Please remove yours.